# Open iCloud Drive root folder in-app modal view

Tags: ios

I've been trying to figure out how to open (in-app) the iCloud Drive root folder in iOS, but I can't seem t find this.

An example of this can be seen in the [Scanbot app](https://scanbot.io/), which opens up a modal view with the root folder of iCloud Drive.